# Deprecated: Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated

Tags: php, hosting, wpbakery

Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)` in /home/cobbktpr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/editors/class-vc-frontend-editor.php on line 673

This is the code on line 673.

```
$host = isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ?

     $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ?

     $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME'];
```

I'm a beginner so please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: For the record, this error is related to the WPBakery Page Builder plugin for Wordpress (plugins/js_composer). The problem is most likely that you are using PHP 8, and the plugin is not compatible with that yet. Use PHP 7.

Comment: It seemed that your WPBakery version is not up to date, and not compatible with your PHP version.

It can be fixed by:
- downloading and installing a new version of WP Bakery
- fixing the 673 line just by adding parenthesis

So just replace :
  `$host = (isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] : isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] )) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME'];`

By

`if ( isset( $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {
   $host = $s['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
  } else {
   $host = ( isset( $s['HTTP_HOST'] ) ? $s['HTTP_HOST'] : $s['SERVER_NAME'] );
  }`