# How can i make js_composer plugin works with PHP 8 or higher?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am new here and i hope you can help me,

my hosting provider forcing me to upgrade to PHP 8 from 7.4 and i have a WP site with Anahata v 1.4 Theme installed. I upgraded the PHP version but WP giving me an error and i couldn't react the site with that error. i deactivated everything and i narrowed down to this file /wp-content/plugins/js_composer.
when i deactivate this file the site is readable, but the whole site is just code like

```
[vc_row content_width="grid" content_aligment="center" css=".vc_custom_1483025434590{padding-top: 92px !important;background-color: #fafafa !important;}"][vc_column][mkd_separator_with_icon icon_pack="font_awesome" fa_icon="" sep_color="#f7972f" custom_icon="11652"][vc_column_text]
```

instead of real content like actual rows and column [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxiYz.png) (as if i am seeing the page with the simple editor instead of WPBakery Page Builder)

can anyone have an idea how to change something in the js_composer plugin to make it work with PHP 8? or any alternative to that plugin.

i dont see js_composer when i navigate to plugins in my admin daschbord and there are no new version of this Theme avalible.

thanks alot for hearing me.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419004/deprecated-unparenthesized-a-b-c-d-e-is-deprecated (this causes a fatal error, if you fix it, js_composer works in PHP 8.1)